# urwid change palette colors on the fly

Tags: python, colors, urwid

In urwid how can I change colors of a palette on the fly? For example, let's say I wanted change when I press the 'C' button:

```
import urwid

def changeColor(key):
    if key in ('c', 'C'):
        c = "light gray"

c = 'black'

palette = [("text", "black", c)]

text = urwid.Text(("text", u'Hello humans'), align='center')
fill = urwid.Filler(text)
urwid.MainLoop(fill, palette, unhandled_input=changeColor).run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `register_palette_entry`. It's a method found in `Screen`, which is available as a public member of the `MainLoop`.

After calling this method with parameters of choice, make sure to redraw the screen - for example, with `screen.clear()`.

Below is a working example - hit `c` to flip between light red and light gray background.

```
import urwid

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flip = False
        palette = [('text', 'black', 'light red')]
        text = urwid.Text(('text', u'Hello humans'), align='center')
        self.fill = urwid.Filler(text)
        self.loop = urwid.MainLoop(self.fill, palette, unhandled_input=self.key_press)
        self.loop.run()

    def key_press(self, key):
        if key in ('c', 'C'):
            self.flip = not self.flip
            self.loop.screen.register_palette_entry('text', 'black', ['light red', 'light gray'][self.flip])
            self.loop.screen.clear()
        if key in ('q', 'Q'):
            raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

Main()
```